# Planar transformation of similar points

Tags: geometry, linear-transformations

I have two planes $A$ and $B$, represented by $ax + by + cz + d = 0$ and $px + qy + pz + r = 0$.  On one plane, I have a triangle with corners of $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$, $(x_2, y_2, z_2)$, $(x_3, y_3, z_3)$, and a similar triangle represented by $(x_4, y_4, z_4)$, $(x_5, y_5, z_5)$, $(x_6, y_6, z_6)$ on the second plane.

I need to calculate the matrix M which transforms each coordinate from triangle $1$ to triangle $2$.

I believe this is the same matrix which would transform plane $A$ to plane $B$, but am at a loss as to how to calculate the matrix.

Comment: What size matrix are you talking about? Unless $d=r=0$ or the planes are identical, there is no $3\times3$ matrix that maps plane $A$ to plane $B$ in the first place. You would have to use homogeneous coordinates and a $4\times4$ matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A $3\times3$ matrix has nine coefficients. Your matrix will perform the transformation

$$Mp_k=p_{k+3}$$ where $k=1,2,3$, and this is equivalent to a system of nine equations in nine unknowns. By regrouping the points in two $3\times3$ matrices,

$$MP_{1,2,3}=P_{3,4,5}$$ or $$M=P_{3,4,5}P_{1,2,3}^{-1}.$$

By contrast, the two planes convey only four parameters, of which one is redundant. So this is not sufficient to fully define the matrix (think that a plane can rotate onto itself).

Comment: Does the fact that the two triangles are similar (same angles and proportional length sides) not give you enough information?

Comment: @CraigT: my answer says that you do have enough information, so why worry ?

Comment: oh, so the matrix P1,2,3 is [x1, x2, x3 
                                         y1, y2, y3
                                         z1, z2, z3 ]
and by finding the matrix P^-1 I can calculate M correctly?

Comment: This answer was initially confusing because I was unfamiliar with the notation you have used, but after more study it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the planes.

Use the three points to define an orthonormal basis, $\hat{u}$, $\hat{v}$, $\hat{w}$:
$$\begin{aligned}
\vec{u} &= \vec{p}_2 - \vec{p}_1 \\
\hat{u} &= \displaystyle \frac{\vec{u}}{\lVert\vec{u}\rVert} \\
\vec{t} &= \vec{p}_3 - \vec{p}_1 \\
\vec{v} &= \displaystyle \vec{t} - \frac{\vec{t}\cdot\vec{u}}{\vec{u}\cdot\vec{u}}\vec{u} \\
\hat{v} &= \displaystyle \frac{\vec{v}}{\lVert\vec{v}\rVert} \\
\hat{w} &= \hat{u} \times \hat{v}
\end{aligned}$$
The three unit vectors $\hat{u}$, $\hat{v}$, and $\hat{w}$ are orthogonal, and define a rotation matrix $\mathbf{R}_1$,
$$\mathbf{R}_1 = \left [ \begin{matrix} \hat{u} & \hat{v} & \hat{w} \end{matrix} \right ]$$
where the vectors are vertical, three rows and one column each, so that $\mathbf{R}_1$ has three rows and three columns.

Do the same for the second set, getting $\mathbf{R}_2$.

Because both $\mathbf{R}_1$ and $\mathbf{R}_2$ are orthogonal, their inverse is their transpose, and
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{R}_{1 \to 2} &= \mathbf{R}_2 \mathbf{R}_1^T \\
\mathbf{R}_{2 \to 1} &= \mathbf{R}_1 \mathbf{R}_2^T \\
\end{aligned}$$

Please note that $\mathbf{R}_{1 \to 2}$ is a rotation that brings the relative orientation of points $1$, $2$, and $3$ to match those of $4$, $5$, and $6$.  $\mathbf{R}_{2 \to 1}$ is the inverse one, and the two are transposes of each other.

It isn't important, but the rotation $\mathbf{R}_1$ brings $\vec{p}_2 - \vec{p}_1$ to the positive $x$ axis, the part of $\vec{p}_3 - \vec{p}_1$ that is perpendicular to that to the positive $y$ axis, and $z$ axis being defined from those using the right-hand rule.  The same for $\mathbf{R}_2$ and the second set of points.  The combined transform is one that brings coordinates back to this common basis, then to the basis defined by the other three points.  (Rotation matrices are combined by multiplying them together, first rotation rightmost.)